# Blurring part of the screen - optimisation

Tags: opengl, glsl

I develop 3d menu and sometimes I need to blur only part of the screen. I use a forward rendering. I create a frame buffer object with 3 color attachments. Rendering looks like this:

- bind fbo
- render objects which  are blurred to the first texture
- bind the first texture
- perform vertical blur and save a result in the second texture
- bind the second texture
- perform horizontal blur and save a result in the third texture
- unbind fbo (render to the default fbo)
- bind the thrid texture
- render the third texture
- render objects which are not blurred

I can use subroutines to reduce overhead during switching shaders. I also found the following [article](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/09/efficient-gaussian-blur-with-linear-sampling/) . Do you have any other ideas how to optimize above rendering ?

Answer (score 1):

That is the standard way of doing a Gaussian blur however, you can use only 2 textures like this:

- bind the original texture
- blur horizontally to the second texture
- bind the blurred horizontally texture
- blur vertically to the original texture